# Jain-Sip Authentication

Tags: java, sip, jain-sip

I'm working with the Jain Sip library, trying to create a connection to an asterisk server.  I've been working with the textclient example app from this page:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/introduction-jain-sip-090386.html

but this doesn't actually authenticate with the server.  I can send messages to users on the server, but I normally require a user/password authentication on the server.

As far as I can tell I have to use the "javax.sip.OUTBOUND_PROXY" property, but I can't find any documentation on how to set a username or password.  Has anyone else had any success with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the example from here http://code.google.com/p/jain-sip/source/browse/#git%2Fsrc%2Fexamples%2Fauthorization

Why do you need to go this low level, you might be better off with using a SIP Servlets Container such as Mobicents http://code.google.com/p/sipservlets/

Answer (score 9):

The best example I have found on registration is found [here](http://vkslabs.com/sip-register-request-using-jain-sip/).
Here is the gist of if just in case the link dries-up one day:

> REGISTER request is used to update the current location of a user on
>   the REGISTRAR server. The application sends a REGISTER message
>   informing the server its current location which in turn is stored in
>   location server. When a caller calls a user the proxy server uses this
>   information to find the location of the callee.
>
> Register request should be sent by the client periodically. The
>   validity of the REGISTER request is determined by the Expires header.
>
> **Flow**
>
> [image]
>
> **Sample Request**
>
> ```
> REGISTER sip:sip.linphone.org SIP/2.0
> Call-ID: 0a0f14355fa76ae6435b98bfe085baf9@223.1.1.128
> CSeq: 1 REGISTER
> From: <sip:vkslabs@sip.linphone.org>;tag=-1427592833
> To: <sip:vkslabs@sip.linphone.org>
> Max-Forwards: 70
> Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 223.1.1.128:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-323532-2a454f4ec2a4213f6d6928eba479521d
> Contact: <sip:vkslabs@223.1.1.128;transport=tcp>
> Content-Length: 0
> ```
>
> Now lets see how to construct the above request using the NIST SIP
>   Stack.
>
> First step is to create a class that implements the SIPListener. Make
>   sure your SIP Stack is Initializing NIST JAIN SIP Stack.
>
> 1. Create Call-ID header
>
>    CallIdHeader callIdHeader = this.sipProvider.getNewCallId();
> 2. Create CSeq header
>
>    CSeqHeader cSeqHeader = this.headerFactory.createCSeqHeader(cseq,
>      "REGISTER");
> 3. Create From header
>
>    Address fromAddress = addressFactory.createAddress("sip:" + username + '@' + server); 
>      FromHeader fromHeader = this.headerFactory.createFromHeader(fromAddress,
>      String.valueOf(this.tag));
> 4. Create To Header
>
>    ToHeader toHeader = this.headerFactory.createToHeader(fromAddress, null);
> 5. Create Max-Forwards header
>
>    MaxForwardsHeader maxForwardsHeader = this.headerFactory.createMaxForwardsHeader(70);
> 6. Create a Via header
>
>    ArrayList viaHeaders = new ArrayList(); 
>      ViaHeader viaHeader = this.headerFactory.createViaHeader(this.ip, this.port, "tcp", null);
>      viaHeaders.add(viaHeader);
> 7. Create contact header
>
>    this.contactAddress = this.addressFactory.createAddress("sip:" + this.username + '@' + this.ip + "transport=tcp");
>
>    // Create the contact header used for all SIP messages. 
>      this.contactHeader = this.headerFactory.createContactHeader(contactAddress);
>
> Once all the headers are created it is time to create the request
>   itself.
>
> ```
> request = this.messageFactory.createRequest("REGISTER sip:" + server + "SIP/2.0\r\n\r\n"); 
> request.addHeader(callIdHeader);
> request.addHeader(cSeqHeader); 
> request.addHeader(fromHeader);
> request.addHeader(toHeader); 
> request.addHeader(maxForwardsHeader);
> request.addHeader(viaHeader); 
> request.addHeader(contactHeader);
> ```
>
> Now that the request object is created with all the necessary headers
>   it is time to send the request.
>
> ```
> inviteTid = sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(request); // send the request out. 
> inviteTid.sendRequest();
> ```
>
> Once the request is sent successfully the response will be passed to
>   the application using the processResponse callback in SIPListener.
>
> ```
> public void processResponse(ResponseEvent responseEvent) { 
>   int statusCode = responseEvent.getResponse().getStatusCode(); 
> }
> ```
>
> **Code**
>
> ```
> public void register(Response response) {
>   try {
>   cseq++;
>   ArrayList viaHeaders = new ArrayList();
>   ViaHeader viaHeader = this.headerFactory.createViaHeader(this.ip,
>   this.port, "tcp", null);
>   viaHeaders.add(viaHeader);
>   // The "Max-Forwards" header.
>   MaxForwardsHeader maxForwardsHeader = this.headerFactory
>   .createMaxForwardsHeader(70);
>   // The "Call-Id" header.
>   CallIdHeader callIdHeader = this.sipProvider.getNewCallId();
>   // The "CSeq" header.
>   CSeqHeader cSeqHeader = this.headerFactory.createCSeqHeader(cseq,
>   "REGISTER");
>
>   Address fromAddress = addressFactory.createAddress("sip:"
>   + username + '@' + server);
>
>   FromHeader fromHeader = this.headerFactory.createFromHeader(
>   fromAddress, String.valueOf(this.tag));
>   // The "To" header.
>   ToHeader toHeader = this.headerFactory.createToHeader(fromAddress,
>   null);
>
>   // this.contactHeader = this.headerFactory
>   // .createContactHeader(contactAddress);
>
>   request = this.messageFactory.createRequest("REGISTER sip:"
>   + server + " SIP/2.0\r\n\r\n");
>   request.addHeader(callIdHeader);
>   request.addHeader(cSeqHeader);
>   request.addHeader(fromHeader);
>   request.addHeader(toHeader);
>   request.addHeader(maxForwardsHeader);
>   request.addHeader(viaHeader);
>   request.addHeader(contactHeader);
>   if (response != null) {
>   retry = true;
>   AuthorizationHeader authHeader = Utils.makeAuthHeader(headerFactory, response,
>   request, username, password);
>   request.addHeader(authHeader);
>   }
>   inviteTid = sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(request);
>   // send the request out.
>   inviteTid.sendRequest();
>   this.dialog = inviteTid.getDialog();
>   // Send the request statelessly through the SIP provider.
>   //            this.sipProvider.sendRequest(request);
>
>   // Display the message in the text area.
>   logger.debug("Request sent:\n" + request.toString() + "\n\n");
>   } catch (Exception e) {
>   // If an error occurred, display the error.
>   e.printStackTrace();
>   logger.debug("Request sent failed: " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
>   }
> }
> ```

You can also view the reference post on authentication [here](http://vkslabs.com/digest-authorization-in-sip-with-md5-challenge).
Here is the gist of if just in case the link dries-up one day:

> During a SIP request if the server responds with 401 Proxy
>   Authentication Required or 401 Unauthorized then it means the client
>   has to replay the same request again with MD5 challenge.
>
> The client should use nonce value from the response header
>   WWW-Authenticate.
>
> WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="sip.linphone.org",
>   nonce="JbAO1QAAAAA3aDI0AADMobiT7toAAAAA", opaque="+GNywA==",
>   algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
>
> The client should use nonce to generate the MD5 challenge and make the
>   original request again with the Authorization header.
>
> Steps to create the MD5 Challenge
>
> 1. Create first MD5 hash using username + “:” + realm + “:” + password
>
>    String a1 = username + ":" + realm + ":" + password; 
>      String ha1 = toHexString(mdigest.digest(a1.getBytes()));
> 2. Create second MD5 hash using request_method + “:” + request_uri
>
>    String a2 = request_method.toUpperCase() + ":" + request_uri; 
>      String ha2 = toHexString(mdigest.digest(a2.getBytes()));
> 3. If qop in the response header is “auth” then the final MD5 hash is calculated using step 3a else if it is undefined or empty refer step
>      3b.
>
> 3a. Create the final MD5 string using ha1 + “:” + nonce + “:” + nonceCount + “:” + cNonce + “:” + qop + “:” + ha2
>
> ```
> String finalStr = ha1 + ":" + nonce + ":" + nonceCount + ":" + cNonce + ":" + qop + ":" + ha2; 
> String response = toHexString(mdigest.digest(finalStr.getBytes()));
> ```
>
> 3b. Create the final MD5 string using ha1 + “:” + nonce + “:” + ha2
>
> ```
> String finalStr = ha1 + ":" + nonce + ":" + ha2; 
> String response = toHexString(mdigest.digest(finalStr.getBytes()));
> ```

Comment: When I try to use the code from this post I receive NPE 
line:
`ViaHeader viaHeader = this.headerFactory.createViaHeader(this.ip,
  this.port, "tcp", null);`

Comment: @johndaw16 is your headerFactory null? You must create it. For example: SipFactory sipFactory = SipFactory.getInstance(); sipFactory.setPathName("gov.nist"); headerFactory = sipFactory.createHeaderFactory();

Comment: `ViaHeader viaHeader = this.headerFactory.createViaHeader(this.ip, this.port, "tcp", null)` Last parameter should be branchID string. Try it that way.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at the ClientAuthenticationHelper class which encapsulates the steps above : See the package gov.nist.javax.sip.clientauthutils

I believe there's an example of usage in the code base.